# ui.helper index in stop() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Trying to get the index in the following example is driving crazy. I am using this base code:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

On `stop()` event, I am trying to know what is the index of the new element dragged. For example:

```
[Drag me down]
-------------
[Item 1]
[Item 2]
[Item 3]
[Item 4]
```

If I release the new item between `Item 2` and `Item 3` somehow I'd need to get a `2`.  As you can see below, `ui.helper.index()` is not valid, because it is returning the index of the original element ([Drag me down] element) :

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        // ...
        receive: function( event, ui ) {
            var indexAtReceive = $(this).data("ui-sortable").currentItem.index();
        }
    });

    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        // ...
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            // Here indexAtStop is the index of the original element, 
            //but not the new dragged element
            var indexAtStop = ui.helper.index();
        }
    });
```

Let me know if you need to more relevant code or test. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want `ui.item.index()` in this case inside your stop function

```
$( ".draggable" ).sortable({
    // ...
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var indexAtStop = ui.item.index();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure? I do not see `ui.item` in stop event's documentation, I think that is why I get a `ui.item is undefined` error.

Comment: ah, i see this is setting up draggable, not sortable. that is why. why are you implementing both sortable and draggable? sortable implements draggable. the stop function you pass to sortable() has a second param of ui that will have item hanging off of it. you must not have access to that because you're implementing draggable at this point, not sortable.

Comment: I implemented both guys becase (1) Draggable: In order to add new elements. (2). Sortable: In order to manage item's order (eventually rows in a db). However I see your point at sortable's stop function.

Comment: Please, correct your answer in order to accept it. I have tested it and works great

Comment: updated to set up on sortable instead of draggable (which is what it sounded like your issue was)